# Sharing and synchronizing object b/w BackgroundWorker and main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

**Not a duplicate of** [Sharing objects between a BackgroundWorker and main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171881/sharing-objects-between-a-backgroundworker-and-main-thread)

I've a `BackgroundWorker` processing a queue (read an array) which is managed at the main thread. When the `BackgroundWorker` has already started processing the queue, main thread should be able to update the queue and this update should be visible to  `BackgroundWorker`.

If queue is passed as an argument to `RunWorkerAsync()`, it is isolated from any changes until execution returns to main thread (at `RunWorkerCompleted` or `ProgressChanged`)

Am I at right place using `BackgroundWorker`? If yes, is the sync I am looking for achievable? If no, any alternatives?

Comment: You can use a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BlockingCollection<T>` which is specifically designed for this task, and is thread safe. It uses a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` under the hood.

On the background thread:

```
foreach(var item in theQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // Process item
}
```

On the main thread:

```
theQueue.Add(item1);
theQueue.Add(item2); // etc
theQueue.CompleteAdding();
```

You can make changes to the queue in the main thread while you're reading it from the background thread. The `foreach` loop will process all elements, it will block waiting for new element when the queue is empty, and it will exit when it has processed everything (which is signaled by the `CompleteAdding` call).